# offset().top is giving wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this js to add class to current section, and add class to current navigation element based on data attribute.

```
var cutoff = $(window).scrollTop(),
    cutoffRange = cutoff + 88,
    curSec = $('#main-page').find('.s-active'), // Current section
    curID = $(curSec).attr('id'), // Current section ID
    curNav = $('.navigation').find('li[data-navSections*="'+curID+'"]'); // Find current menu item

    $('.navigation li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    $(curNav).addClass('current-menu-item');

$('.section').each(function(){

    if ($(this).offset().top > cutoff && $(this).offset().top < cutoffRange) {
        $('.section').removeClass('s-active')
        $(this).addClass('s-active');
        return false; // stops the iteration after the first one on screen
    }

});
```

This is example html

```
<section id="section-home" class="s-active"></section>
<section id="section-about" style="margin-top: 990px"></section>
<section id="section-section"></section>

#section-home {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

#section-about,
#section-section {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

First seection is kind of parallax, margin-top to second section is added by another script.

The script above works great but doesn't add class to first fixed home section. Isn't this a bug with offset().top?

---

jsFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/f5ans6g6/

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: There's no bug with `offset()`. So note the difference between `offset()` and `position()`. Your problem maybe is that `margin-top: 990px` is added **after** offset is calculated. So the bug is in your code. Provide a jsfiddle.com reproducing the issue and we can help you better

Comment: check this `$(this).offset().top > cutoff` if both are Integer, sometimes this is also my problem

Comment: Here :) http://jsfiddle.net/f5ans6g6/

Answer (score 3):

It is a typo ;) 
Within this code: `$('.section').each(function(){});` you are pointing to a class named `.section`. This is not available.

Try this:

```
$('section')
```

Comment: Good eyes man :) sometimes we read superficially and we don't note this smallest and important things